# Controller returning error randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, if-statement

Ruby on Rails 3

In my controller index() is am defining instance variables. Yesterday this worked fine. Today I am getting this error:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
app/controllers/grandstreamers/resellers_controller.rb:7:in `block in index'
app/controllers/grandstreamers/resellers_controller.rb:5:in `each'
app/controllers/grandstreamers/resellers_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Here is my controller code:

```
4 @certs = Certificate.all
5 @certs.each do |h| 
6  @id = h.user_id 
7  if @train = (User.find(@id).reseller_id)
8  end
9 end
```

Why is it trying to find a User without an ID? That is a good thing. I would hope my Users have IDs.

If I remove the loop the error is gone. I also tried:

```
@certs = Certificate.all
@certs.each do |h| 
  @id = h.user_id 
  if (User.find(@id).reseller_id)
    @train == User.find(@id).reseller_id
  end
end
```

Same error,  any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have a Certificate record without a user_id.  Is that valid for how your model is supposed to work?

Comment: Your second code block would work if you changed the If line to this  `if (User.find(@id))`

Comment: You are correct. I destroyed it, and all is well. Thanks! Post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a Certificate record without a user_id.  Either remove that record, or better yet, add some validation to your Certificate model to ensure this field is populated.

Alternatively, your second code block would work if you change the If line to `if (User.find(@id))`